# RecyclerView fragment does not appear

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to create an app to display data in a recyclerview. However, when I run it, the main view is blank (the toolbar and navigation drawer work fine). I have meticulously looked over my code for errors and looked at similar problems, but nothing has worked so far. I have tested the asynctasks, which work, but the info won't display.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private  DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private static ListView mDrawerList;
private static ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private static String zipCode = "<zipcode>";
private static String street = "<address>";
public static String[] officeList = null;
public static Elements positionLinks = null;
public static int positionSelected;
public CardFragment currentFragment;
public static String[] namesOfCandidates;
public static String[] partiesOfCandidates;
public static String[] occupationsOfCandidates;
public static String[] candidateLinks;
public static boolean gotCandidates = false;

public static Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    officeList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.offices_array);
    new AsyncPositions().execute();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, officeList));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_favorite).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_settings){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
        return true;
    }else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_favorite){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Favorited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
        // as a favorite...
        //remember to change this to something else - or maybe just a starred thing for elected officials
        return true;
    }else {
        // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
        // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_buttons, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

    /**
     * Swaps fragments in the main content view
     */
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        positionSelected = position;
        //try {
            new AsyncCandidates().execute();
       /* }
        catch(InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ExecutionException ee){
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }*/


        //change the cards to info about candidate
        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(officeList[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }

public String pollingPlaceInfo(){
    //document.getElementsByClassName("PollingPlace_polling-place-content_ucq")[0].innerText;
    return null;
}

//Gets the information about the specific candidate chosen by the card view
// requests position on drawer and candidate number (index) to pinpoint which candidate
// returns 2d array that contains each issue as well as info about it
public String[][] getIssues(int position, int candidate) {
    return null;
}

//asynctask to pull the positions for the nav drawer
private static class AsyncPositions extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.context);
    String[] positions;
    private String zipCode;
    private String street;
    private String urlString = "";
    private Elements positionLinks;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        pdLoading.show();
        zipCode = MainActivity.zipCode;
        street = MainActivity.street;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Document doc = null;

        urlString = "http://votersedge.org/en/ca/search?zip="+zipCode+"&address="+street;

        try {
            //get initial landing page to find most recent election
            doc = Jsoup.connect(urlString)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36")
                    .timeout(12000)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .get();
            //get the link to the most recent election page
            String newLink = "";
            boolean nullpe = false;
            try{
                doc.body().getElementsByClass("MultipleElections_upcoming-elections_3C2 col-md-12").first().child(1).attr("action");
            }
            catch(NullPointerException npe) {
                newLink = "http://votersedge.org"+doc.body().getElementsByClass("MultipleElections_recent-elections_rsw col-md-12").first().child(1).attr("action");
                nullpe = true;
            }
            if(!nullpe) {
                newLink = "http://votersedge.org" + doc.body().getElementsByClass("MultipleElections_upcoming-elections_3C2 col-md-12").first().child(1).attr("action");
            }

            doc = Jsoup.connect(newLink)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36")
                    .timeout(12000)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .get();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        Elements positionHeaders = doc.getElementsByClass("ContestsList_jurisdiction-group-label_1Kt");
        positionLinks = doc.getElementsByClass("ContestsList_contest-link_W44");



        //get size of positions list for easy access
        int sizeOfList = positionLinks.size()/2;
        //create array that will be returned
        positions = new String[sizeOfList];
        int l = 0;
        int k=0;
        int j=2;
        for(int i=0; i<sizeOfList; i++){
            try{
                doc.getElementsByClass("ContestsList_accordion-content_1rY card-content").first().child(k).child(j);
            }
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ibe){
                k++;
                j=2;
                l++;
            }

            try{
                doc.getElementsByClass("ContestsList_accordion-content_1rY card-content").first().child(k).child(j).child(0);
            }
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ibe){
                j++;
                l++;
            }

            while(!doc.getElementsByClass("ContestsList_accordion-content_1rY card-content").first().child(k).child(j).child(0).tagName().equals("h4")){
                j++;
                l++;
            }
            positions[i] = positionHeaders.eq(l).text() + " " +doc.getElementsByClass("ContestsList_accordion-content_1rY card-content").first().child(k).child(j).child(0).child(0).child(1).text();
            j++;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        MainActivity.officeList = positions;
        MainActivity.mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.context,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, MainActivity.officeList));
        MainActivity.positionLinks = positionLinks;
        pdLoading.dismiss();
    }

}
private class AsyncCandidates extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.context);
    private Elements positionElements;
    private int position;
    private String[] namesOfCandidates;
    private String[] partiesOfCandidates;
    private String[] occupationsOfCandidates;
    private String[] candidateLinks;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pdLoading.show();
        positionElements = MainActivity.positionLinks;
        position = MainActivity.positionSelected;

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Document doc = null;
        String link = "http://votersedge.org"+ positionElements.eq(position).attr("href");
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(link)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36")
                    .timeout(12000)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .get();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        //getting links for reference for further information gathering
        //need to create initial array to get all links (each has 1 duplicate in the array)
        // and then create another array to get rid of duplicates
        Elements links = doc.body().getElementsByClass("CandidateCard_candidate-link_2m1");
        String[] cLinks = new String[links.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<links.size(); i++) {
            cLinks[i] = "http://votersedge.org" + links.eq(i).attr("href");
        }
        candidateLinks = new String[links.size()/2];
        for(int i=0; i<links.size(); i+=2){
            candidateLinks[i/2] = cLinks[i];
        }
        //getting names of candidates
        Elements names = doc.body().getElementsByClass("CandidateCard_candidate-name_234 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 flush-cols");
        namesOfCandidates = new String[names.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<names.size(); i++){
            namesOfCandidates[i] = names.eq(i).text();
        }
        //getting political parties of candidates
        Elements attributes = doc.body().getElementsByClass("CandidateCard_candidate-attributes_3qD col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 flush-cols");
        partiesOfCandidates = new String[names.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<names.size(); i++){
            partiesOfCandidates[i] = attributes.eq(i).first().child(0).text()+" Candidate";
            if(partiesOfCandidates[i].equals(" Candidate")) partiesOfCandidates[i] = "Candidate";
        }
        //getting occupations of candidates
        occupationsOfCandidates = new String[names.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<names.size(); i++){
            occupationsOfCandidates[i] = attributes.eq(i).first().child(1).text();
        }

        gotCandidates = true;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        MainActivity.namesOfCandidates = namesOfCandidates;
        MainActivity.candidateLinks = candidateLinks;
        MainActivity.partiesOfCandidates = partiesOfCandidates;
        MainActivity.occupationsOfCandidates = occupationsOfCandidates;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArray("names", namesOfCandidates);
        bundle.putStringArray("parties", partiesOfCandidates);
        bundle.putStringArray("links", candidateLinks);
        bundle.putStringArray("occupations", occupationsOfCandidates);


        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        MainActivity.this.currentFragment = (CardFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        if (MainActivity.this.currentFragment == null) {
            MainActivity.this.currentFragment = new CardFragment();
            MainActivity.this.currentFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, MainActivity.this.currentFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }else{
            MainActivity.this.currentFragment = new CardFragment();
            MainActivity.this.currentFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, MainActivity.this.currentFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
        pdLoading.dismiss();
    }

}

}
```

CardFragment.java

```
public class CardFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerView MyRecyclerView;
String[] namesOfCandidates;
String[] partiesOfCandidates;
String[] occupationsOfCandidates;
String[] candidateLinks;



@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("test", "fragment has been created");

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.getArguments();
    namesOfCandidates = this.getArguments().getStringArray("names");
    partiesOfCandidates = this.getArguments().getStringArray("parties");
    candidateLinks = this.getArguments().getStringArray("links");
    occupationsOfCandidates = this.getArguments().getStringArray("occupations");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card, container, false);
    MyRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    MyRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager MyLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    MyLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    if (namesOfCandidates.length > 0 & MyRecyclerView != null) {
        MyRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(namesOfCandidates));
    }
    MyRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(MyLayoutManager);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
    private String[] list;

    public MyAdapter(String[] Data) {
        list = Data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycle_items, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.titleTextView.setText(list[position]);
        holder.mainTextView.setText(CardFragment.this.partiesOfCandidates[position]+"Candidate\n"+CardFragment.this.occupationsOfCandidates[position]);
        holder.arrowImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.length;
    }
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView titleTextView;
    ImageView arrowImageView;
    TextView mainTextView;

    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        mainTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);
        arrowImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.arrowImageView);
        arrowImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                int id = (int)arrowImageView.getTag();
                if( id == R.drawable.ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp) {

                    //MOVE TO NEXT SCREEN
                }
            }
        });





    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</FrameLayout>

<!-- Action bar -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_left_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_right_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

recycle_items.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="3.2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />


        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrowImageView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height"
            android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more troubleshooting, and after some tinkering I found that getting rid of the MyToolbar object and the ActionBarDrawerToggle the content showed up. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in your conditional checking, as logical AND should be `&&` not `&`.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work - it still does not display it. Plus, that would not explain the lack of an exception.

Comment: did you already make sure that `namesOfCandidates` in your fragment contains the right element?

by the way using '&' won't display an exception as it is a valid operator which is bitwise AND.

Comment: namesOfCandidates contains the right element. It seems like the fragment just won't display, since by getting rid of the nav drawer and action bar the recyclerview appears